# Replace the last match of a regex

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace just the last match of a regex? I know it has something to do with the ? but how do we use the lookahead correctly? There are some similiar questions on SO but they all just need to strip one last character and I can not get this adapted for a whole regex match.

```
// EDIT: the last regex returned "" not "/0/" - the difference is the ?= instead of ?!
String foo = "/0/a/b/c/a/b/c/d".replaceAll("(?=a.b.c).*$","");
assert (foo, "/0/a/b/c/"); // I keep getting /0/   :-(
```

Comment: When I run exactly what you have, `foo` is blank, not `/0/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following:

```
String foo = "/0/a/b/c/a/b/c/d".replaceAll("a.b.c(?!.*a.b.c).*", "");
```

The pattern will match `a.b.c` that is not followed by another `a.b.c`.

Comment: Beat me to it :)  You could also group the `a.b.c` and refer to it in the lookahead: `(a.b.c)(?!.*\\1).*`.

Comment: yes this does the trick! thx PS @davidfmatheson and yes the expression "(a.b.c)(?!.*\\1).*" will work too.

Comment: @davidfmatheson, backreference will not work if `a.b.c` parts are different. For example: `/0/a/b/c/a/b-c/d`.

Comment: @falsetru That's true!  I just assumed the OP wanted to exclude true double-matches.  Could be that they want to exclude `a.b.c` even if they're different.